# EF6 no agrega todas las tablas al modelo conceptual

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle-11g, entity-framework-6

Buen día, tengo un proyecto de asp.net mvc que realice con EF5 y no tenia problemas al actualizar ni al traerme tablas nuevas, sin embargo decidí utilizar el EF6 para probar las funcionalidades que tiene pero resulta que cuando quise actualizar mi esquema para que me agregara unas tablas nuevas no me las agrego solo lo agrego a la carpeta de model.store pero no a mi modelo conceptual, borre el modelo para generarlo de nuevo y ahora lo que hace es que solo me trae unas cuantas tablas pero las modificadas y creadas recientemente no.

Estoy trabajando con Oracle 11g. 
Necesito de su ayuda.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola David, has intentado actualizar el modelo? le has dado un re-build e intentar guardar todo?

Comment: Es buena idea presentar tus fuentes para ver el estatus. Esto es insumo para poder ayudarte